# Search bar works with values typed or clicked by user

Tags: javascript, search

I'm trying to have a search bar with 2 behaviors:

1. User enters the values into the search bar
2. User can click on the elements from several lists

Case 1. is working just fine.

Case 2. Right now, the user needs to hit `enter` to validate the search.
BUT I would like to display the results as soon as the value is entered into the input field, so the user doesn't have to hit enter.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Below is the code:

```
function recherche(){
  var search = $('#search').val();
  if(search.length < 1) {
    return null;
  };

  var results = json.filter(function (el) {
    var s = search.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (var key in el) {
      for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (el[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(s[i]) != -1) {
          s.splice(i,1);
          i--;
          if (!s.length) return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
  displaySearchResults(results);
};

var items = document.getElementById("filter");
var item = items.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(this.textContent || this.innerText);
    document.getElementById("search").value = (this.textContent || this.innerText);
  });
}

$(function() {
  recherche();
  $('#search').keyup(recherche);
});
```

Comment: Your using `keyup` already allowing you to call the `recherche` on every key press. You should also fire off any ajax calls to retrieve updated search results.

Comment: Just call `recherce()` after `document.getElementById("search").value = (this.textContent || this.innerText);`